# How would a cloud app get the client's local device information?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How would a cloud web app get Client Device Information such as IP address, Serial Number, etc?

Looking to have an app developed for tracking asset conditions within the school.  Just want to make sure my ask is possible before I list it for review.

Basically the user goes to a webpage and fills out a condition report and submits it.  I'm wanting to automatically identify the Chromebook or Laptop that is submitting the condition report.  With Chromebooks especially, the S/N on the board is not what always is on the case plastics (due to repairs).  The aim of making this automatic is to keep data correct.

I could identify the device by serial number, asset number, or local LAN IP.  Could potentially identify by any other persistent hardware id that doesn't change.

**Thoughts on possible solutions / workarounds:**

Maybe there is a unique hardware hash or identifier that Chrome supplies that is persistent and I don't know about.  I could manually build a lookup table if its not appropriate to use it directly.

It looks like the WebRTC method no longer works for obtaining local IP address  - unless there is a way to force the Chrome Flags for specific sites through Google Workplace policies.

I could create a web service that runs behind the firewall and returns the IP address of the requestor.  The client side JavaScript would use that when communicating with the cloud web app and if it cannot connect to the local web service then it prompts the user for the serial number as a last resort.

I could create and force install an extension that the webpage can use to obtain the IP address...
E.g. https://github.com/DoctorLai/what-is-my-ip/

Just wondering if there is an easier way than the above ...  One that would work even if the Chromebook wasn't on site...

Thanks